# Solution of Dirichlet Problem with Itô's formula with Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, expected-value

I have two questions to the application of [Itô's formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUpUC.png)  characterizing the solution to the [Dirichlet problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVOI1.png)? (Here I put a picture with the two underlined points I'm referring to.)

1. Why is the term $\sum_{i=1}^d \int_0^t \partial_i u(B_s)dB_s^i$ a bounded martingale starting in 0?
2. Why is $u(x)=E_x[\phi(B_{\tau_G})]$?

I would be really, really thankful for answers!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There is a typo in these notes. Instead of $t$, it should say $\tau_G$ in the limit of integration. The stochastic integral (with $t \wedge \tau_G$ as the limit of integration, that is) is automatically a local martingale starting in 0. It is bounded by the definition of $\tau_G$ and the facts that $G$ is bounded and $u \in C^2(\overline{G})$. Hence, it is also a global martingale. Altogether this yields that its expectation is always 0. For your second question, note that $E_x(u(B_0))=u(x)$ and simply rearrange the equation.

Comment: Thank you!! Are you saying that every stochastic integral is automatically a local martingale starting in 0?

Comment: Essentially yes. Depending on your approach to the theory, the very definition of the Ito integral yields that if $M$ is a locally square integrable martingale (such as Brownian Motion) and $X\in L_{loc}^2(M)$, then $\int_0^t X_sdM_s$ defines a local martingale that vanishes for $t=0$.

Comment: Why is it the case that $E_x[u(B_0)]=u(x)$? Is it because $B_0=0$ and therefore, we consider $E_x[u(0)]$ and this is $x$ because we can interpret it as the starting point of $u$?

Comment: @lea5619 No, not quite. The notation $E_x$ indicates that you are taking the expectation with respect to the probability measure $P_x$ under which $B_0=x$. So, since $P_x(B_0=x)=1$, you get $E_x(u(B_0))=u(x)$.

Comment: How do we know that $\partial_i u(B_s) \in L^2_{loc}(B)$? And $L^2_{loc}(B)$ stands for predictable integrands for local martingales, right?

Comment: $L_{loc}^2 (M)$ stands for predictable and locally square integrable with respect to $\langle M\rangle$. Knowing this, can you answer the first question yourself?

Comment: I never used the notion "locally square integrable". Only "square integrable". Or "the integral w.r.t. continuous local martingales" where I referred to in my last comment. In this definition our integrands have to be predictable and satisfy $\int_0^t H^2_s d[X]_s < \infty$ a.s. for all $t \geq 0$. Is this $L^2_{loc}(M)$?

Comment: This property is a little stronger than what I call locally square integrable, but it works here.

Comment: I don't see it. Why is $\partial_iu(B_s) \in L_{loc}^2(M)$?

Comment: As $G$ is bounded, $\overline{G}$ is compact, and since $u\in C^{2+\epsilon}(\overline{G})$, we have in particular $\partial_i u \in C(\overline{G})$.  Putting this together, $|\partial_i u|$ is bounded by some constant $c\in(0,\infty)$, and hence

$$\int_0^t \partial_i u(B_s)^2d[B]_s^i=\int_0^t \partial_i u(B_s)^2ds\le c^2 t<\infty.$$

Comment: To your first comment: You mentioned that the martingale is bounded and starting in 0. Therefore it is constant 0. I only know a theorem saying that if the variation is bounded the martingale is constant 0.... does this apply? is a bounded process always of bounded variation?

Comment: No, I did not say that. I said that its **expectation** is constant to zero. And a bounded process need not be of bounded variation, just think of Brownian motion that is frozen when leaving a ball.

Comment: Thankyou! We say that the integral is $0$. How does this follow? Do we have bounded variation? And if yes, why?

Comment: Didn't I just explain that?

Comment: I think you didn't explain why $\int_0^{{\tau}_G} \partial_i u(B_s) dB^i_s=0$ follows. Did You?

Comment: It doesn't. But its expectation is 0.

Comment: But in the picture "dirichlet problem" I uploaded in my post we are claiming that it is 0 and we wrote zero inside the expectation which means that it refers to the integral and not to the expectation, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh, you are referring to **this** integral now (but somehow still wrote the other one in your comment above?). Well that one vanishes since $u$ is harmonic, $\Delta u =0$.

Comment: No, I am still referring to the first integral on the right side. There's written $0$ inside the expectation.

Answer (score -1):

1. A stochastic integral (from $0$ to $t$) of a local martingale with respect to a Brownian Motion is, by construction, a local martingale starting in $0$. Now, a bounded local martingale $X_t$is an actual martingale by dominated convergence (pick a localising sequence $(T_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}},$ then $X_{t\wedge T_n}\to X_t$ in $L^1$ as $n\to\infty$, and the corresponding Markov Property of $t\mapsto X_{t\wedge T_n}$ then ascends to $t\mapsto X_t$).

   Now, you can apply the Optional Sampling Theorem to get 2.

Comment: Note that $u(B_t)$  and its derivatives are bounded since they are continuous on the closure of $G$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, @WoolierThanThou!
How do we know that $\delta_i u(B_s)$ is a local martingale?